# Can I plug/unplug a USB device without a physical change in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, port

A method to Connect / Disconnect a USB device "softly".

Hey, Assume I have a USB device connected to my PC, I want to enable/disable the port it is connected via computer so that I don't have to unplug/plug my device each time.

P.S : Device is a Microcontroller Board ( powered by USB port ) , so I don't want it to be active all the time. I want to deactivate it when appyling changes to code etc. and then activate that port so I can load my code into it again.

Is there a method to do so ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Device is a Microcontroller Board ( powered by USB port )

Most USB enabled µC types can "unplug" themself.

The idea is to put the USB data pins (usually called `D+` and `D-`) into "output low" state for about one second at startup. This forces USB to be recognized as "disconnected".

After that is done, re-configure the pins to for their USB function and initialze the USB as usual.

Note that this method is not possible on old style boards that still use USB2UART chips instead of hardware USB inside the µC itself.

Comment: Either i could not explain right or you get it another way. I don't want to program microcontroller to do so, I want my PC to close a USB port ( PC's own port ) temporarily. Nevermind the Microcontroller example, say i want to disconnect/connect  a normal USB Flash drive "via Windows settings". Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not possible with windows OS and normal of-the-shelf hardware. 
My personal solution would be another microcontroller switching a p-channel mosfet on VBUS.

Comment: Thanks, i don't have that much knowledge but anyway it was not a crucial topic, just an interest.